What exactly does it mean for something to be contingent?
X being contingent means that X could have been otherwise. But what exactly do people mean when they say this and why is this significant?
For example, I can certainly imagine my cup to not be on my table. But why does this imply that the cup could not have been on the table? What if we live in a deterministic universe where given the initial conditions of the universe, the cup could have not failed to be on the table that it is.
If contingency purely means “I can imagine it to be otherwise”, what is the practical significance of this? Sure, I can imagine the cup not being on my table, but I can also imagine the cup to suddenly grow wings and start flying.
So what exactly does it mean for X to be contingent and why is this significant?

Does "contingent" have a meaning in philosophy that's different from its ordinary definition?

If you want to define it so strongly, then any fact that is not a logical contradiction is contingent. Wittgenstein, Tractatus 6.37 "A necessity for one thing to happen because another has happened does not exist. There is only logical necessity." According to Humpty Dumpty a word means whatever one wants it to mean (though Alice has her doubts about that).

There is the "possible world semantics," according to which we imagine a set of all "possible worlds," and say an event is contingent if it happens in at least one of them but not in some other.
But this leaves a huge open question. Which worlds are possible? It's just kicking the can down the road; we haven't really said anything about which propositions are possible, we've only transformed it into an even more unanswerable question about which worlds are possible.
In colloquial usage, we say something is "possible" if we can't rule it out at the moment with the information available to us. Say a police detective wants to track down a suspect. At first he says it's possible the suspect could have gone north along route 8, and it's possible the suspect could have gone south along route 8. Then a report surfaces that the suspect was spotted at a gas station north of the crime scene along route 8. So now the detective rules out that the suspect went south, and says it's only possible the suspect went north.
But nothing about the state of affairs regarding the suspect changed; the only change was what information was available to the detective. Possible world semantics cannot deal with this. In possible world semantics, whether an event is possible or not is an objective fact independent of what anyone thinks about it. That does not reflect the detective's situation or other colloquial usages of the word.
In colloquial usage, when not talking about the practically useless "possible world" formalism, we mostly use the word "contingent" when making future plans based on uncertain events (contingencies). A contingency is a future event we can neither rule out nor confirm at the moment with the information available to us. So we might make a plan for if it happens, and another plan for if it doesn't happen, so we would be prepared in either case.
Note that whether we can "rule out" or "confirm" an event is always a matter of degree. There is always a chance that an event could happen, or fail to happen; we can never reach warranted 100% certainty about any future event. (The suspect on route 8 could have changed direction after the gas station, or the person spotted at the gas station could have been someone else who just coincidentally looked like the suspect). So we say an event is contingent if our confidence that it will happen fails to reach an ambiguous threshold, and if our confidence that it will not happen also fails to reach that ambiguous threshold.

There are many different modalities, hence many different kinds of possibility and necessity. Your example is concerned with what is epistemically possible, i.e. what might be true consistently with what is known. Since a person's knowledge changes over time, what is epistemically possible for that person changes. If we choose to model this in terms of possible worlds, it does not mean that the worlds change, but it affects which worlds are accessible. The accessibility relation that corresponds to the detective's state of knowledge reflects which worlds are consistent with what he knows.

@Bumble It's inadequate to simply restrict to "worlds consistent with what he knows." The set of worlds consistent with the detective's state of mind (i.e. worlds containing the detective in that state of mind) includes every possible way that state of mind might have arisen, and practically nothing can be purely deduced from the fact of being in that vast set of worlds. Certainly can't infer that the suspect fled north, also can't infer that the suspect is not an alien invader capable of teleporting, or any number of outlandish possibilities.

The detective's judgments of possibility exclude those outlandish possibilities, because his credence in them is sufficiently low. So the possible-world semantics of "restricting to worlds consistent with what he knows" cannot accurately reflect the detective's judgments (and the fact that a neutral observer informed of the situation might reasonably say that his judgments are true).

Perhaps I am misinterpreting you and you meant not to restrict worlds that contain the detective in that state of mind, but rather restricting to worlds in which the detective's beliefs are actually correct. First point is that the detective might not be in any of those worlds. Second point is that it still doesn't cohere with the detective's inferences; if the detective believes and is correct that the suspect was spotted at the northern gas station, there are still vast numbers of worlds in which the suspect turned around and went south or something else outlandish happened.

Whether possibilities such as the suspect being an alien are outlandish or not is irrelevant. The question is not about plausibility but about contingency. Whether the suspect is an alien is a logical contingency and if the detective does not know that the suspect is an alien and does not know that they aren't then it is also an epistemic contingency for the detective. Low credences also have nothing to do with contingency. You seem to be answering a completely different question from the one asked.

@Bumble Credences have everything to do with what we call possible or impossible in actual use. When we call something impossible, we hardly ever mean there is literally no way it could happen. Because we wouldn't be able to call anything impossible if we took that interpretation strictly; the word would be worthless. If a formalism fails to capture the very useful and necessary shades of gray in how we use the words "possible" and "impossible," the problem is with the formalism.

@Bumble Also the question asker didn't use the phrase "logical contingency," he said "what exactly do people mean when they say this" and proposed "I can imagine it to be otherwise" as a possible meaning. So we can infer from his phrasing that he is not asking about some formalized idea of logical contingency, but rather about the way ordinary people (such as the police detective) actually use the word.

I disagree completely. If someone uses the word 'impossible' when they actually mean 'highly unlikely' then they are misusing the word. People also often say things like, "This is extremely unique," when they mean, "This is extremely rare". It is a misuse. Things are impossible when they are ruled out in some way. There are different ways of ruling things out, so there are different kinds of impossible: logically impossible, physically impossible, scientifically impossible, epistemically impossible, etc.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

To @causative's point, in philosophy the term "contingent" is a modal term indicating whatever is "contingent" was not necessary - the world could have been otherwise.
For example, I'm walking in a forest and stub my toe on a thorn. I can imagine a world where, for various reasons, I did not step on the thorn - hence my stepping on the thorn is contingent: none of those scenarios appear to be impossible, hence we say my stepping on the thorn was contingent.
Contrast that with necessary things - there are no other possibilities or ways things could have turned out (on pain of contradiction usually).
The extent to which possible worlds are really "out there" is a controversial thing. For example, how do we resolve the following?

Objective randomness: Is there true indeterminism in the world. Some events may have statistical connections but they are not deterministic, and hence nature could have come out differently (e.g., maybe quantum phenomena).

Principle of plentitude: Is there a reason to think reality is limited to one instantiation of a world? What is stopping the universe (writ large) from exploring every possible avenue as a matter of necessity?


We arrive at different conclusions depending on if we accept/reject each of these.
Reject 1, Reject 2: This is the classical determinist view. At rock bottom we are forced to posit a brute necessity (God, initial conditions). Possible worlds are only linguistic tools for expressing inability to rule it out (per @Causitive).
Reject 1, Accept 2: Modal realism (ala Lewis). The ultimate expression of the "Copernican Principle" that humanity is not privileged. Nature/reality cannot be constrained to just one world - the fullness of reality is literally everything. It's not even clear that conceivability or adherence to classical logic is sufficient, because our logical sense evolved from living in this world.
The huge benefit here is (a) we don't need spooky randomness in the world and (b) no brute necessities -- existence exists necessarily and everything else follows from that - so highly explanatory from a few assumptions. Some say its not parsimonious but they mistake "number of entities" from what I think is the more important thing, which is "number of commitments." What appears as randomness is really epistemic: there are a number of worlds "close" the the one we are actually in and we don't know which one we are in with the given information, but science has been able to learn some of the tendencies (at least in our neck of total reality).
Big downside: We cannot (nor likely will we ever) be able to empirically support this (except tangentially if we find evidence of colliding universes .. but still not a "world" in the philosophical sense of independent and non-interacting).
Accept 1, Reject 2: Some kind of "fluctuation metaphysics" that says our world came from an indeterministic initial state. How things worked out so well (or even if they did) to allow life is an open question here.
Accept 1, Accept 2*: I would say this is actually no different than modal realism, since each way the world could be would also be -- not sure in what sense there is objective changes.
Anyway, one way to summarize. Hope this helps.

If your answer is intended to respond to mine, then what do you say about the possibilities considered by the police detective? I take it to be true that initially at time T1, it was possible from the detective's perspective that the suspect could have fled north or south, and that afterwards at time T2, it was true that the suspect must have fled north. But you cannot represent these truths with possible-world semantics, unless you propose that the set of possible worlds is different between time T1 and T2 and is dependent on the detective's state of mind.

Having the possible worlds change over time is not a feature of possible-world semantics I'm familiar with. And then what about the fact that none of the detective's judgments can be perfectly certain, so he calls impossible what he is sufficiently confident isn't the case? Possible-world semantics do not allow for that; an event that happens in 0.00000001% of possible worlds is just as "possible" as an event that happens in 90% of them. (Assuming a measure can even be defined across possible worlds so that "90% of possible worlds" is even a meaningful phrase at all.)

@causative - no it wasn't in response to your post; actually, I agree with it. I was giving some view of the landscape of how "possible" and "contingent" can be defined in a metaphysical sense. To your point about possible worlds changing, I agree - a world is either possible or it isn't, it doesn't make sense to say it is possible at T1 and not at T2. For your police example, I imagine him taking a epistemic approach to possible worlds -- there are some facts, and he is restricting his  consideration of possibility to only the worlds where those facts are true.

These "epistemic possible worlds" seem to be just ideal Bayesian inference, especially when you consider that the detective wants to consider likelihood rather than just existence, so he needs a probability distribution over "epistemic possible worlds." So then the "possible worlds" are nothing but the outcomes of a random variable in the detective's subjective credence, and propositions are the events of this random variable. That's okay as far as it goes, but departs from the usual possible-worlds discourse. Also humans at best can only approximate Bayesian inference.

@causative correct -- I saw the inspector's thinking as fundamentally Bayesian vs making claims on what worlds actually exist or are possible.


A state of affairs “S” is contingent when there is at least one
possible world where “S” is a fact, and at least one possible world, where “S” is not a fact.
Analogously “S” is necessary when “S” is a fact in all possible
worlds. That’s a precise formal definition.

But it opens up at once the
following question: How to ensure that “S” is the same state of
affairs in different possible worlds? That’s necessary to compare it
in diferrent possible worlds.
The concept of possible worlds may
sound rather intuitive. But it is a difficult and involved task to
make it precise, see possible worlds.



"May sound rather intuitive" - it's just kicking the can down the road to which worlds you decide to call possible and which you don't. That's no less thorny a question. In colloquial usage, "possible" means we can't at the moment rule it out with the information available to us. That's a far cry from possible world semantics.

In simple terms, something is contingent if it is neither necessarily the case nor necessarily not the case. But there are many different kinds of modality, e.g. logical, physical, epistemic, deontic, nomic, metaphysical, etc. Hence there are correspondingly many different kinds of contingency.

A proposition is logically contingent if it is neither a logical truth nor a contradiction.
A belief is epistemically contingent for me if it may or may not be true consistently with what I know.
An action is legally contingent if it is neither absolutely mandatory nor unlawful.
An event is physically contingent if it neither certain to happen nor certain not to happen.
Etc.

Physical determinism is one kind of modal necessity. In practice it is somewhat more complicated to spell out exactly what determinism means and how it relates to certainty. But if you believe the universe is deterministic and that every event either happens or does not happen of necessity then you would not believe that events in the universe are contingent in that specific sense.
As to why contingency is significant... Possibilities and necessities have an important impact on our reasoning and decision making. When we reason we need to understand what is logically possible and impossible. When we design and build things we need to understand what is possible and impossible within the bounds of scientific laws. When we make plans for the future we need to take into account what might or might not happen: even if the universe is deterministic we don't know the future so there are epistemic contingencies.
Even when we know some proposition to be true, there is value in considering its contingency. I might narrowly escape some misfortune and consider that if things had been slightly different the outcome would have been disastrous for me. That fact provides an incentive to be better prepared against that contingency in future.

From Conifold:

It means nothing "exactly", as with "necessary" or "possible", until one specifies what kind of modality (imaginative, practical, normative, physical, nomic, metaphysical, conceptual, logical, etc.) they have in mind or the context makes it clear. Practical significance, if any, depends on that specification. It is controversial whether imaginability or conceivability imply logical possibility, for example, see SEP.


You really should reward yourself by allowing yourself to harvest some reputation. All you have to do is riff a bit in your own language to explicate, maybe throw in an additional reference or two. I hate to think of you laboring away and not receiving some form of recognition for your contributions. ; )

You ask:

What exactly does it mean for something to be contingent?

That all depends on the language community or language user's intention when using that particular token as a tool in discourse. The general dictionary definitions provided by MW provide 5 definitions! From MW:

1
: dependent on or conditioned by something else
Payment is contingent on fulfillment of certain conditions.
a plan contingent on the weather
2
: likely but not certain to happen : possible
3
: not logically necessary
especially : empirical
4
a
: happening by chance or unforeseen causes
b
: subject to chance or unseen effects : unpredictable
c
: intended for use in circumstances not completely foreseen
contingent funds
5
: not necessitated : determined by free choice

And those are just the use of the term in venacular English. I can only imagine how much ink and how many bytes have been dedicated to the cause of dealing with the topic "exactly". We can see that contingency circulates around some important concepts: 1) possibility 2) probability 3) chance 4) dependency. Rather than responding in detail as these other contributors have bravely elected to do, I simply suggest that you reference a number of articles in the SEP:

The Epistemology of Modality (SEP)
Possible Objects (SEP)
Modal Logic (SEP)
Possible Worlds (SEP)
Inductive Logic (SEP)

Modality and logic are primarily the study of contingency in various contexts. A learned man one said that logic is the study of what follows from what. And in this sense necessity, possibility, and probability are very much the core of what it means to study logic itself, so the idea that you'll get an "exact" answer is a bad way of thinking about how language is used. So, exactly what contingency means in philosophical language communities is like asking what does it mean to use the term 'logic' or 'necessity' or 'inference'. It might even be an essentially contested concept.
